# $http.get returns actual php script instead of running it (yeoman, grunt)

Tags: php, angularjs, pdo, gruntjs

I'm building a "simple" `AngularJS` app with an articles newsfeed. My articles are stored in a `mysql` database, and I extract them using `php PDO`. I used to do this using `AJAX` with a simple `LAMP` configuration (`php5, mysql, apache2`), and everything worked as intended.

Now I'm trying to rebuild the project with `yeoman` (`bower`+`grunt`), and when I try to call my .php script with a `$http.get` service, the response is the actual script content (it returns the code instead of running the query).

I have no idea if this is a problem with my code, my grunt configuration or something else. So far I haven't tried to make a distribution version yet.

Here are the relevant pages:

the view:

```
<div id="articles-sidebar">
    <h2>Search articles archive:</h2>
    <form id="searchbox" method="post">
        <input name="searchword" type="text" placeholder="author, title, keyword...">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <div id="author">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="articles-feed">
</div>
<div id="comments-box">
    <form id="comment" method="post">
        <textarea name="comment-text" placeholder="Your comment..."></textarea>
        <input name="submit-comment" type="submit" value="Post Comment">
    </form>
    <div id="comments-feed">
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller:
'use strict';

angul

```
ar.module('ptcAngularJsApp')
    .controller('ArticlesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.articles = [];

        $http.get('/scripts/php/articles.php').
            success(function(response) {
                $scope.articles = response;
                console.log(response);
            }). //end http get success
            error(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }); //end http get error
      });
```

db_auth.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=topdecka_PTC;charset=utf8",$username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

articles.php:

```
<?php

require('db_connexion.php');

//search form
if (!empty($_POST["searchword"])) {
    $searchword = $_POST["searchword"];
    $query = $db->prepare(
        'SELECT articles.title, articles.posted, articles.extract, authors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cat_name) AS cat_name
        FROM articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
        WHERE articles.author_id = authors.id
        AND articles.id = article_categories.article_id
        AND article_categories.category_id = categories.id
        AND ((title LIKE :searchword) OR (extract LIKE :searchword) OR (body LIKE :searchword) OR (name LIKE :searchword) OR (cat_name LIKE :searchword))'
        ); //end DB QUERY
    $query->execute(array(":searchword" => "%" . $searchword . "%"));
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    //turns timestamp into integer
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
      $result[$i]['posted'] = strtotime($result[$i]['posted']);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
} 
//article title link
else if (!empty($_POST["title"])) {
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $query = $db->prepare(
        "SELECT articles.title, articles.posted, articles.body, authors.name, authors.img, authors.bio, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cat_name) AS cat_name
        FROM articles INNER JOIN authors ON articles.author_id = authors.id
        INNER JOIN article_categories ON articles.id = article_categories.article_id
        INNER JOIN categories ON article_categories.category_id = categories.id
        WHERE title LIKE :title; SELECT comment.user_id, comment.text, comment.posted FROM articles RIGHT JOIN comment ON articles.id = comment.article_id
        WHERE title LIKE :title;"
        ); //end DB QUERY
    $query->execute(array(":title" => $title));
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    $result[0]['posted'] = strtotime($result[0]['posted']);
    $query->nextRowset();
    $result2 = $query->fetchAll();

    for($x=0; $x < count($result2); $x++) {
        $result2[$x]['posted'] = strtotime($result2[$x]['posted']);
    }

    echo json_encode(array('article'=>$result, 'comments'=>$result2));
    die();
}
//loading article comments
else if (!empty($_POST["comment_load"])) {
    $comment_load = $_POST["comment_load"];
    $query = $db->prepare(
            "SELECT comment.user_id, comment.text, comment.posted FROM articles RIGHT JOIN comment ON articles.id = comment.article_id
            WHERE title LIKE :comment_load;"
        );
    $query->execute(array(":comment_load" => $comment_load));   
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    for($x=0; $x<count($result); $x++) {
        $result[$x]['posted'] = strtotime($result[$x]['posted']);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
//saving comment
else if (!empty($_POST["comment-text"])) {
    $input_text = $_POST["comment-text"];
    $query = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO comment (user_id, text, article_id)
        VALUES (101, :input_text, 4);'
        );
    $query->execute(array(":input_text" => $input_text));
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
//default GET article feed
else {
    $query = $db->prepare(
        'SELECT articles.title, articles.posted, articles.extract, authors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cat_name) AS cat_name
        FROM articles, authors, categories, article_categories 
        WHERE articles.author_id = authors.id
        AND articles.id = article_categories.article_id
        AND article_categories.category_id = categories.id'
        ); //end DB QUERY
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    //turns timestamp into integer
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
      $result[$i]['posted'] = strtotime($result[$i]['posted']);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
```

gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2015-06-21 using generator-angular 0.11.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true,
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]

);
};
```

any idea on what to try to get this working is welcome. thanks

Comment: Looks like your server isn't configured to run PHP

Comment: yeh that's probably it the more I think about it. after installing grunt I just went with the basic configuration (installed yeoman angular generator), ran bower install, npm install then grunt serve

Comment: do you have apache php installed ? and is it running?

Comment: yeh, I have apache2 running php5 and mysql. just tried running the previous version of my app (the AJAX one) and it loads the database content using the same script

Comment: added gruntfile.js to the main post

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like you're using $http.get to deliver a local file instead of making an http request to the server, so Apache isn't being called (and therefore PHP is not running). $http.get should be pointed at whatever URL would execute that script, like `http://localhost/articles.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$http.get('/scripts/php/articles.php')
```

to

```
$http.get('http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/scripts/php/articles.php')
```

Off course you need to replace YOURDOMAIN.COM with localhost or any other domain you are using.

Comment: I pointed the url to the apache service (the one the old app is using), and now instead of returning the script it returns `null` when `error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
   }); ` gets run

Comment: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/PTC_php/db_queries/articles.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

Comment: I think I just need to get grunt to run my php scripts, I'll try to figure it out now that I know what the problem is

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry so I did not gave the answer in detail. Yeah, now that you know you can explore it in detail and fix it properly :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that grunt isn't running my php scripts.

When I ran `grunt build` to get a distribution version, then ran that version with apache, I get my database query results fine.

I will try to figure out how to integrate php into grunt, so I can run it in my development environment without building it every time, and update this anwser once I get to it.

If anyone else knows of a good tutorial, generator or library that does this please write it up.